# Растягивание дочерних элементов в Vbox

Tags: java, javafx

Добавляю в контейнер `VBox` два объекта: `Label` и `TableView`. Последним элементом является `TableVew`, у него ставлю `maxHeight=MAX_VALUE`, но `TableVew` не растягивается на всю высоту `VBox`. В чем может быть проблема?

```
<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Label text="Label" />
      <TableView maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="C1" />
          <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="C2" />
        </columns>
      </TableView>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

Comment: версия джавы 7 или 8?

Comment: попробуй еще такой варинат VBox.setVgrow(tableView, Priority.ALWAYS);